Email Security Compliance Options Explained
We've all seen the "Email Security Compliance" email deliverability options at some point but their description is so obscure that I could never quite figure out what they actually do:

At least with the second option, I could figure out that emails being sent have a Sender header being added to them.
From:
From: Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
To: info@test.com

To:
From: Foo Bar <foo@bar.com>
Sender: <noreply@salesforce.com>
To: info@test.com

But does it do more than that? And what's with the first option? And why does it need to be turned on for the second option?
Most importantly - how should they be set? I've seen many orgs and all kinds of combinations. With the added security nowadays I feel like they should be turned on - but what for? And why do some guides (regarding SPF, DKIM & DMARC) recommend turning it off? Does anybody have some deeper insights into this confusing topic?

SPF/DKIM FAQ is a good start. Your Qs: 1. No 2. https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=sf.emailadmin_enable_email_security_compliance.htm&type=5 3. Because that's how they implemented it 4. how should they be set - See #2 5. what for - see FAQ 6. why do some - what guides are those (please edit your question)
